# How simulate click button or send data without click?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a code of modal box in html, css

```
<div aria-hidden="hide" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                One fine body...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code is in main layout, and now when i want show this modal i need put button in html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg push-top push-bottom" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"> Test </button>
```

But i don't want put any buttons, because i want show this modal when server send back in ajax function some data. If data should show modal then i want modal visible. But i don't know is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have data, then you can trigger it manually: you can read about this events here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

and if you want to hide:

```
 $('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is custom made "Modal Window" u can just use:

```
$("#modalID").show();
```

when server send back.

Else if this is plugin read his documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood your question, so just trying:
With jQuery you can always emulate a click with

```
$('#IdOfMyButton').click()
```

or submit a form with

```
$('#IdOfMyForm').submit()
```

Comment: User doesn't want to put a button or trigger event on that button. He directly wants to show model based on data received in ajax.